# Angular Material Theme being partially loaded

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having issues with Material Theme loading some of it's features.

I can't seem to find the source of the problem, and I've read the 'Getting Started' from material.angular.io several times, using the CLI commands to update my project.

[image: where is my primary button color?]

html:

```
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" buttonType="submit"
    [disabled]="inquiryForm.invalid || inquiryForm.pristine">
    <mat-icon>library_add</mat-icon> Inquiry
  </button>
```

styles.scss:

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

@import "~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";
@import "~roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css";
```

angular.json:

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ]
```

I'm using Angular 8, all packages related are 8+ version.

As shown in the image, the button does not seem to recognize 'primary' color, but the MatInputs can. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you imported the `MatButtonModule` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `app.module.ts` (or your custom Material module if you created one) and add the following lines:

```typescript
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ // or 'exports:' in case of custom Material module
    // ...
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```